# Dozer mapping from parent field to nested/child field

Tags: java, mapping, dozer

I am struggling for dozer mapping for nested object. I want to map object field to field of this object child. for example I have these classes.

```
class Parent {
    private Child child;
    private Long childId;

    // setter - getter
}

class Child {
    private Long id;

    // setter - getter
}
```

and my mapping is:

```
</mappings>
<configuration>
    <map-null>false</map-null>
</configuration>
<mapping>
    <class-a>com.indraep.Parent</class-a>
    <class-b>com.indraep.Parent</class-b>

    <field>
        <a>childId</a>
        <b>child.id</b>
    </field>
</mapping>
</mappings>
```

By this setup, I can't map Parent.childId to Parent.child.id.

However It works if I try the opposite map from Parent.child.id to Parent.childId by using this mapping:

```
<field>
    <a>childId</a>
    <b>child.id</b>
</field>
```

Any idea how to solve this problem? or it's not possible to do it with dozer?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by adding this field exclude config:

```
<field-exclude>
    <a>child</a>
    <b>child</b>
</field-exclude>
```

from the log, it seems dozer have mapped Parent.childId -> Parent.child.id, but in the next step it gets override by Parent.child -> Parent.child so the Parent.child becomes null.

Another problem is if Child class has some other fields and I need to mapped it as well (except for child.id which is mapped from Parent.childId), how to solve this?